# Join BigQuery tables on dynamic dataset

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to reduce the number of queries and I got stuck.
We have `workflow.configs` table that has a column `dataset`. And there is another table `[dataset].config_files`, where `dataset` is a value from the first table's `dataset` column.

Now, when I retrieve data from tables, I perform 2 queries: the one to get a record with a dataset from the `workflow.configs` table, and then having a dataset I retrieve data from the `[dataset].config_files` table.

Is it possible to join these two queries somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes sure, you need to construct a script. That uses variables and execute statements.

```
DECLARE var_dataset STRING;
DECLARE var_query STRING;
SET var_dataset = (SELECT mydataset from table limit 1);

SET var_query = "select * from " || var_dataset || ".config_files";
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE var_query;
```

Comment: No exactly what I was thinking of, but it worked, thanks! :)